# How to connect netmiko and django application

Tags: javascript, django, netmiko

As netmiko specifies there should be a device type, IP Address, username and a password so I made a model named devices and what I am trying to do is when I click on each device created in a table it should execute netmiko with the four credentials such as Device type, IP Address, Username and password for the specific device selected or clicked and it should allow me to type a command which can be executed by a press of button

can you please help me with the code

```
Model.py
class Device(models.Model):
    CISCO1 = 1
    CISCO2 = 2
    CISCO3 = 3
    CISCO4 = 4
    DEVICE_TYPES = (
        (CISCO1, 'cisco_ios'),
        (CISCO2, 'cisco_nxos_ssh'),
        (CISCO3, 'cisco_s300'),
        (CISCO4, 'cisco_tp_tcce'),
    )
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    publication_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    IP_address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    device_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=DEVICE_TYPES)
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.device_name
```

```
View.py

This is the connection code but I am confused how to get data from the Model (Device) and pass it here or when I select a device from the view it should get the credential to this method

def connection_manage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommandForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            from netmiko import ConnectHandler
            device = {}
            device['device_type'] = 'cisco_ios'
            device['ip'] = 'DESKTOP-CT4RSIT'
            device['username'] = ''
            device['password'] = ''
            cmd = request.POST.get('command', '')
            conn = ConnectHandler(**device)
            output = conn.send_command(cmd)
            return render(request, 'connect.html', {'form': form, 'output': output})
    else:
        form = CommandForm()
        return render(request, 'connect.html', {'form': form})
```

```
form.py

class CommandForm(BSModalForm):
    command = forms.CharField(label='Command to execute')
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        exclude = ['timestamp', 'publication_date', 'device_type']
```

```
connect.html

{% load static %}
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <title>Mannai Co.</title>
    <link href="{% static 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/login.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper fadeInDown">

        <div id="formContent">

            <div class="fadeIn first">
                <br>
                <img src="{% static 'assets/img/manni-png.png' %}" id="icon" alt="User Icon">
            </div>
            <h3 class="fadeIn second">Netminko APP</h3>
            <p>Run command:</p>
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form}}
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Run command!" class="fadeIn fourth" />
            </form>
            {% if request.POST %}
            <p>Command output:</p>
            <pre>{{ output }}</pre>
            {% endif %}

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

urs.py
path('execute/',connection_manage, name='execute_device'),

First Setup needed
when i click on this one it should make me able to enter all details manually and press execute
[image: b]

enter all fields manually and execute
this is the view from the website but whatever I type it still going to connect to cisco_ios
[image: xxx]

output
[image: zzz]

The second Setup needed
when I click on the each filed button it should pop a modal which is currently working with all fields populated and when I type and command and execute it should run for the specified device

[image: table]

[image: running]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work:

```
device['ip'] = 'DESKTOP-CT4RSIT'
```

This either needs to be:

```
device['host'] = fqdn.domain.com
```

or

```
device['ip'] = 1.2.3.4      # The IP address of the device
```